# How many binary words of length $9$ are there that contain 4 $0$s and 5 $1$s?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm studying for a Discrete Mathematics II exam, and I came across this example in the textbook of the course.

The writer proceeds to solve as $\dfrac{9!}{4!5!}=126$ and provides no explanation.

This might probably be too trivial but I've been thinking of this for the past 20 minutes.

What does the solution show? What is that damned $9!$ up there? Surely not the possible 9-length combinations of binary words, that would be $2^9$, much smaller than $9!$.
He then divides by $4!5!$, obviously trying to cut words that violate the two conditions from the result, but I can't make heads or tails of the whole thing, still.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Binomial Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), written as $\binom{n}{r}, ~_nC_r,C(n,r)$ or others, is the number of ways in which you may select $r$ objects out of $n$ total where order is irrelevant.  Equivalently worded, it is the number of ways to partition a set of $n$ objects into two groups, one of which of size $r$.  It is read aloud as "$n$ **choose** $r$."  Such a grouping is often called a *combination* (as opposed to a *permutation*).

One may prove that $\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$ using arguments of symmetry, or combinatorial arguments.  See any textbook for such a proof.

Here, we have nine spaces and we want to **choose** five of the spaces to be occupied by ones.  The remaining spaces will be occupied by zeroes.  In other words, we are partitioning the available spaces into two groups: those that will be occupied by the $5$ ones, and those that will be occupied by the remaining $4$ zeroes.  There are then $9$ **choose** $5$ ways to do this.  I.e. $\binom{9}{5}=\frac{9!}{5!4!}$

Comment: The idea that it was a simple 9 choose 5 went completely over my head. 5 hours of studying will do that to a brain. Thank you for the immaculate answer.

Comment: @DimitrisS. one of the skills often emphasized in an introductory course on combinatorics is how to take a problem type that is less understood and reword it into a problem type that you are more familiar with.  Such is the case here.  Similarly, questions such as counting the number of paths along a grid which use only ups or rights (lattice paths), or questions about the number of ways to distribute identical cookies among children may also be worded in such a way that you can answer with binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

This is the formula for ${9}\choose{4}$ (or equivalently, ${9}\choose{5}$). We're essentially choosing which 4 bits out of the 9 total bits will contain 0. In general, the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$.

Answer (score 1):

This may help.

If the digits were all distinct - as in $123456789$ - then you'd have $9!$ possibilities, simply the number of unique arrangements of nine things lined up.

But the digits aren't all distinct.  Let's replace the $12345$ with $11111$.  There are $5!$ ways to line up $12345$ but only one way to line up $11111$, because you can't tell one $1$ from another.  Hence for every way we can fill in $6789$ in four of the nine spaces, we only have one way to fit the $1$'s in the spaces that are left, not $5! = 120$ ways.  So the number of unique arrangements of the digits $111116789$ is $9!/5!$.

Let's do it again, and replace the $6789$ with $0000$.  Each of the $4!$ ways of lining up the digits $6789$ collapses to one way, which gives you $9!/(5!4!)$.

Comment: Your answer really helped. I only wish I could accept every answer here.

Comment: You're welcome. Believe it or not, I don't think I've ever thought carefully about *why* the combination formula works, so I learned something myself by answering your question!